# event.cancelBubble not working with .live

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to perform one operation on the basis of all `record_row` div onclick . I am doing this by `$('.record_row').live("click",function(){})`. Inside record_row div I put `option_icon` div in which 
I have put an image. I have prevented record onclick by `onclick="event.cancelBubble = true;"`. It is working
fine with `$('.option_icon').click(function(){})` but not working with `$('.option_icon').live("click",function(){})` function.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

**Html :-**

```
<div id="container">
    <ul>
        <li><div id="data_item_1" class="record_row">
                User record displayning here
                <div class="option_icon" onclick="event.cancelBubble = true;">
                    -----
                </div>  
            </div>  
        </li>   
        <li>
            <div id="data_item_2" class="record_row">
                 .........
                <div class="option_icon" onclick="event.cancelBubble = true;">
                    -----
                </div>  

            </div>  
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Jquery:-**

```
$('.record_row').live("click",function(){
    -----------
    -----------
    // working fine
});   

$('.option_icon').live("click",function(e){
       e.stopPropagation();
    -----------
    -----------
    // Not working
});
```

Comment: [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated and you should use alternatives, but even then, as the documentation says, *calling event.stopPropagation() in the event handler is ineffective in stopping event handlers attached lower in the document; the event has already propagated to document* (setting `cancelBubble` to `true` being equivalent to calling `stopPropagation()`).

Comment: `event.cancelBubble` is how IE is stopping event propagation, jQuery unifies the interface and provides `event.stopPropagation()`.

Comment: Also, `onclick` and all other inline event handlers are frowned upon. Don't do this. You **literally never** need to mix JS code and HTML, *especially* since you have jQuery.

Comment: Thanks, What should i use here instead of `event.cancelBubble` to prevent parent onclick event.

Comment: @Roopendra: If both event handlers are bound with `.live` (event delegation) then it might actually just work. You might have to use a newer jQuery version though.

Comment: @Felix Kling , Thanks for your suggestion. I will try your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I'd try handling the click event like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.option_icon', function(ev){
    ev.stopPropagation();
    ev.cancelBubble = true;

    -----------
    -----------
    // Not working
});
```

You can find more info about this [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)

Comment: It is not working on ajax loaded content in my case

Comment: So, as @FrédéricHamidi suggested, you should try the `on` method instead `live`, since it is deprecated (see the edited answer)

Answer (score 0):

For your first handler, check where the event originated using the jQuery event object's [`target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target) property. Since it might have also originated in a child of `div.option_icon`, you can use the [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) method to figure out if it was somewhere within that `<div>` or not.

```
$('#container').on('click', '.record_row', function (e) {

    // if event bubbled up from .option_icon, ignore
    if ( $(e.target).closest('.option_icon').length > 0 ) return;

    //your code here...

});
```

Your second handler would simply be

```
$('#container').on('click', '.option_icon', function () {
    //your code here...    
});
```

Also, remove the onclick event handlers from your HTML markup